# Creating shiny apps that are indexable (crawlable) by Google?

Tags: r, shiny

This is not a programming language per se, I hope that it's okay asking this here. I am just starting to learn how to use shiny to create new applications, and would be interested in adding these apps to my website.

From my understanding, the finished apps are usually hosted in the shiny servers. I also understand that the apps hosted there cannot be crawled by Google, as the the Google bots would activate the apps each time and therefore unnecessarily drain resources.

Is it possible to host the apps elsewhere so that it can be crawled by Google? If so, how would this be achieved?

Any help is much appreciated.